# MongoDb transform timestamp to date IN query

Tags: mongodb, date

I have an application in which I have to make some stats and I m facing problems with the request.

In fact, what I need is :

- get the sum of a list item
- between two dates (timestamp format in DB)
- group by year and month
- if the task isDone

Actually, I have this query(that doesnt work for sure) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {timestampentre: {$gt: start}, timestampentre: {$lt: end}}},{$project: {isDone: "$isDone", year: {$year: "$year"}, month: {$month: "$month"}}},{$group: {_id: {year: "$year", month: "$month"}, count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

What I need is to translate the "timestampentre" in a MongoDb date during the query.
In fact, I need to get something like this :

```
{$match: {new Date(timestampentre): {$gt: new Date().getTime()}
```

With this, I ll be able to group on the month or the year

I dont know if it's correct or possible, but does it exist something that permit me to transform a timestamp in a date with mongodb ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: As far as I know that is not possible, but...  why not do the other way around and transform the start and end dates into timestamps?

Comment: It's just something to help me becoming better with mongodb, and to understand a bit more the mecanism

Comment: Instead of numeric timestamps save the dates as dates in mongo. It will make your life easier by allowing you to use the date aggregation operators.

Comment: It seems that you want to write a field name into a BSON data dynamically. But basically aggregation doesn't support it currently. You can get it by JS coding.

Comment: Thanks for all, I ll use Mongodb date so